# How to add Facebook share capability to Gluon app

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I've added the `facebook-android-sdk` to my build.gradle dependencies. When I start the login flow, I get the exception:

`NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/common/R$layout`.

I guess this file is created when you build the app with Android Studio, but it doesn't work on Eclipse.
I imported the facebook-android-sdk git repository, and tried to reference it as project in my app project, which didn't work.

Is there a possibility to use Facebook-Login without having to use Gluon-CloudLink?

Comment: It is possible to do it, but it will require some investigation for getting it working. Gluon CloudLink takes the burden away of that. It also provides out-of-the-box support for signing in via Google+, Twitter and GitHub for both iOS and android.

Comment: Gluon Cloudlink is a great solution for handling user authentication, especially for security reasons, but as a backend for a small app it seems like overkill and it is just too expensive.